How can I configure nuxt 3 so that when I directly open a static page generated with npm run generate it works correctly?
My project works fine. After running npm run generate and npx serve .output/public I can correctly access all the functionalities. But if I open the index.html of .output/public through my file system with a double click, it shows me the start correctly but no functionality does its job properly: neither the buttons nor the navigation bar.
This same problem occurred to me programming in Vue 3, but I solved it by setting PublicPath: "" but with Nuxt I have not been able to solve the problem.
I tried setting SSR: false in nuxt.config.ts but it didn't work, neither app: {baseURL: "" } or nitro: {baseURL: "", static: true}
Is there any configuration that allows the project to work correctly by accessing it through the folders?

You are not supposed to open an isomorphic app (or even a VueJS app) just by double-clicking on it.
You need to have a small server running to properly manage the whole state part.
This might be a start
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  nitro: {
    preset: 'browser'
  }
})

I know that there are ways to generate a Nuxt app fully statically too, but then I don't really see how it would manage some dynamic things.
Also, what is the issue of running serve?

I have no problem with serve, my ultimate goal is to be able to deploy the application to github pages, which when doing so behaves in the same way as if I tried to open index.html from the folder. And making the application purely static is the only solution I have found for a correct deployment of nuxt there.

@LioanysLópezGarcía as far as I know you can totally host it on Github because they will have some sort of serve too. If they do not then you could use Netlify, Vercel, Cloudinary, Digital ocean or any kind of other hosting platform. Best part? It is free and has better work flow than Github pages that is quite obsolete nowadays. So don't wreck you entire app because Github is not able to host properly.

@LioanysLópezGarcía If you use generate, GitHub Pages can handle it correctly because it use http(s):// but not file://

@ZihanHu do not recommend GH pages please, it's just bad and every other platforms just does better.

TL;DR: There is no way to do that due to CORS.

Nuxt uses Vite, and Vite uses native ES6 Modules. When you double-click to open an HTML file, the browser will use file:// url, indicating a local file. However, ES6 Module can't be loaded from file:// urls. The request to the entry script will fail, the app won't hydrate.
Unlike file://, http:// or https:// will work. That's why npx serve .output/public will work.
